# Activate flashlight when battery is lower than 10% in android API 21 and above

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-permissions, android-camera2

I'm trying to create an android flashlight app and I'm almost done. I'm facing one problem though. When the battery is below 10% the app starts but the flashlight doesn't come on.

- minSdk is Api 21 (lollipop)
- MaxSdk is Api 23 (M)

Below are the permissions and features included in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<!--for controlling the camera flashlight-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <!--/-->
```

How do I get around this problem.

Comment: i think this is somekind of protection for battery to save some power (cause 10% is not much) and flash light consume a quit large amount of energy. i think you have nothing to do with this

Comment: Yes it is, but I've seen flashlight apps which let the user select a limit(1% to 10%) above which the flashlight would work.

Comment: i am not sure about this point, but if you go back and check those apps, i think they require rooted devices?

Comment: Ya the app I was talking about comes preinstalled with Asus. Guess it would have root access since it's a preinstalled app. Anyways thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: ya, usually a pre-installed app if it's an official ROM, then it has to be a sys app, in that case the app will gain more access than regular apps